# How to decode the application extension block of GIF?

Tags: decode, gif, animated-gif

How to decode the application extension block of GIF?

```
0000300: 73e7 d639 bdad 10ad 9c08 b5a5 0021 ff0b  s..9.........!..
0000310: 4e45 5453 4341 5045 322e 3003 0100 0000  NETSCAPE2.0.....
0000320: 21f9 0409 1900 f600 2c00 0000 0016 01b7  !.......,.......
```

this "

```
21 ff0b  s..9.........!..
    0000310: 4e45 5453 4341 5045 322e 30
```

" is known, but what is "`03 0100 0000`"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following describes GIF Netscape Application extension, taken [from here](http://www.vurdalakov.net/misc/gif/netscape-looping-application-extension).

> The block is 19 bytes long. First 14 bytes belongs to general
>   Application Extension format, syntax is described in [GIF89a
>   Specification, section "26. Application Extension"](http://www.vurdalakov.net/misc/gif/application-extension).
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
>  0  |     0x21      |  Extension Label
>     +---------------+
>  1  |     0xFF      |  Application Extension Label
>     +---------------+
>  2  |     0x0B      |  Block Size
>     +---------------+
>  3  |               | 
>     +-             -+
>  4  |               | 
>     +-             -+
>  5  |               | 
>     +-             -+
>  6  |               | 
>     +-  NETSCAPE   -+  Application Identifier (8 bytes)
>  7  |               | 
>     +-             -+
>  8  |               | 
>     +-             -+
>  9  |               | 
>     +-             -+
> 10  |               | 
>     +---------------+
> 11  |               | 
>     +-             -+
> 12  |      2.0      |  Application Authentication Code (3 bytes)
>     +-             -+
> 13  |               | 
>     +===============+                      --+
> 14  |     0x03      |  Sub-block Data Size   |
>     +---------------+                        |
> 15  |     0x01      |  Sub-block ID          |
>     +---------------+                        | Application Data Sub-block
> 16  |               |                        |
>     +-             -+  Loop Count (2 bytes)  |
> 17  |               |                        |
>     +===============+                      --+
> 18  |     0x00      |  Block Terminator
> ```

You already know the data up to `NETSCAPE2.0`. The next byte `0x03` tells us the next data sub-block length which is always 3 bytes. The following `0x01` is the sub-block ID. For Netscape block, there is only one data sub-block and the ID is `1`.

The following 2 bytes specifies the loop count in little endian — how many times the image frames should be looped, which is 0, and 0 means loop **forever**.

The last byte `0x00` is used to terminate the data block. So when we meet a `0x00` where data sub-block length should be, we know there are no sub-blocks left and we need to stop reading the block.