# How to disable a looping for gif image and save it in c#

Tags: c#, image, gif, system.drawing

In my application, there is an image uploading and if a user wants to upload gif image. I need to disable looping in an image and save it, in the result gif image of a user must be played once and stop after that. Maybe I need to delete pointer from the last frame of gif image? Any ideas?

Comment: *"I need to disable looping in an image and save it"* - means you want to save a certain frame?

Comment: @Sinatr No, gif image it is part of advertisement banner on another site and one of the requirements from this site is gif without infinite looping.

Comment: @Sinatr do you mean, he should save a single frame as an another image and replace it on a client after loop is done?

Comment: Actually no, the gif image is an image which consists of frames, every frame has a pointer to next frame, so I need to remove the pointer from the last frame and save it. I need to modify gif and save it. IMHO

Comment: @PavelKononenko - What you need is removal of Netscape looping extension block. http://www.vurdalakov.net/misc/gif/netscape-looping-application-extension

Answer (score 0):

You need to add or change the Netscape Application extension block. In this block there are 2 bytes to control the looping, see details in the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28486261/3936440

I couldn't find a proper package for GIF manipulation but i think you can use BumpKit as an inspiration as mentioned here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32810041/3936440

or

https://github.com/DataDink/Bumpkit/blob/master/BumpKit/BumpKit/GifEncoder.cs

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, thank you all who tried to helped me.

The gif image has a set of properties which you can get if you know **the specific address of a byte** of each property.
For example, 20737 is looping property.
if this property set to 0 gif image will have infinite looping, but if set this property great than 0 gif image will be repeated infinitely. The [example](http://sourcebrowser.io/Browse/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/src/ImageProcessor/Imaging/Formats/GifDecoder.cs) I placed here.

```
var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path)
var IsLooped = BitConverter.ToInt16(image.GetPropertyItem(20737).Value, 0) != 1;
```

Comment: You should also be aware  of this :- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1255497#c4

Comment: Is this correct, isn't?

Value 0 in "NETSCAPE2.0" means loop forever.
Missing "NETSCAPE2.0" block means 0 repetitions = loop once.
Value 1 in "NETSCAPE2.0" means 1 repetition = 2 loops.
Value 2 in "NETSCAPE2.0" means 2 repetitions = 3 loops.

Comment: Hi Pavel, just checked an image. It is as mentioned in comment. Run this: `gifsicle --no-loopcount  < input.gif > output.gif` and it will remove Netscape extension block and the image does not loops in both chrome & firefox. Confirmed using `xxd output.gif | grep NETSCAPE` and Netscape extension block was removed. Done on ubuntu. Hope it helps. Gifsicle reference - https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/man.html

Comment: By the way, I am not sure how to do in C#, but it would be better to check for the signature of NETSCAPE block and remove the 19 bytes from filestream and save back to stop gif from looping.